# When to dig out carrots for consumption at the latest in autumn?

Tags: carrots, fall-gardening

Starting from which temperature it doesn't make sense anymore to keep carrots in the ground if their final destination is consumption?

I'm in the midst of autumn here and last week we had still 20 °C. Now it has drop to 10-15.

When do they stop growing?

Comment: Just cover the row/bed in straw/leaves/hay and dig them when you want them, right through the winter.